# JIRA Agile sprint with tasks from different projects

Tags: jira, agile, agile-project-management, sprint

I'm currently using Jira Agile for managing my projects.Currently, I have 3 projects: A,B and C. Is there any way to create a Sprint with task from different projects. For example, this week should work on bug fixing so it might be expectable to have 2 bugs from project A, 3 bugs from project B and 2 from project C. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with mdoar, you simply need filters.
I'd create new Issue Type, let's say "Bug_fix_sprint" which is common for all projects, then open tickets with that type in each project, then I'd use Issue Type Filter to add them on dashboard. Or, maybe, I'd create a new dashboard for this sprint

Answer (score 1):

The filter for your board needs to be changed to include the issues you want from all three projects